UNITY и PUN2. Сцены и комната
День добрый! Такой вопрос. При использовании PUN2 в UNITY для создания мультиплеера есть возможность создания комнат и подключения к ним. Ну в общем стандартные функции и всё прекрасно работает, но есть необходимость загружать разные сцены внутри созданной комнаты. Опишу подробнее на примере: Условно есть лобби, куда игроки загружаются и могут там находится, бегать, прыгать и т.д. После определённого момента их всех загружает из лобби на уровень 1 (после него на уровень 2 и т.д.). Сами эти уровни представляют собой отдельно созданные и независимые сцены. Подскажите как реализовать и вообще возможно ли так реализовать, чтобы после захода игроков в комнату, можно было загружать различные сцены. При этом установленные при заходе в комнату ники игроков не изменялись, а зашедшие новые игроки загружались не в первую сцену с лобби, а в текущую, где все (например, в уровень 3). На счёт загрузки не в первую сцену это второстепенная задача, было бы куда важнее знать как вообще реализовать данную подгрузку сцен без выхода из комнат. Буду признателен любой идеи и советом литературы или источника, где можно почитать про что-либо похожее, ибо сам в инете инфы не нашёл
